# Authlogic automatic logout on timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic, user-inactivity

I am using the Authlogic gem in my application, and I need users to be logged out automatically after 15 minutes of inactivity. Can somebody tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On User model:

```
acts_as_authentic do |c|
  c.logged_in_timeout(5.minutes)
end
```

on UserSession model:

```
self.logout_on_timeout = true
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this and it works. The problem for me is that it doesn't show the user as logged out until they attempt to do something after being inactive for 15 minutes. Is there an easy to to achieve this?